# Angular: Как деструктизировать код в конструкторе модели данных?

Tags: typescript, angular

```js
export class Street {
    glob_id: string;
    id: string;
    is_edited: string;
    parents_levels: Array<number>;
    parents_names: Array<string>;
    name: string;
    region_id: string;
    region: string;
    county: string;
    area: string;
    city: string;
    city_district: string;
    place: string;
    street: string;
    additional_territory: string;
    additional_territory_subject: string;
    constructor(street?) {
        street = street || {};
        this.glob_id = street.glob_id || '';
        this.id = street.glob_id || '';
        this.is_edited = street.is_edited || '';
        this.name = street.name || '';
        this.parents_names = JSON.parse(street.parents_names) || [];
        this.parents_levels = JSON.parse(street.parents_levels) || [];
        this.region_id = street.region_id || [];


        for (let i = 0; i < this.parents_levels.length; i++) {
            switch (+this.parents_levels[i]) {
                case 1:
                    this.region = this.parents_names[i];
                    break;
                case 2:
                    this.county = this.parents_names[i];
                    break;
                case 3:
                    this.area = this.parents_names[i];
                    break;
                case 4:
                    this.city = this.parents_names[i];
                    break;
                case 5:
                    this.city_district = this.parents_names[i];
                    break;
                case 6:
                    this.place = this.parents_names[i];
                    break;
                case 90:
                    this.additional_territory = this.parents_names[i];
                    break;
                case 91:
                    this.additional_territory_subject = this.parents_names[i];
                    break;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Дело в том, что нужно сделать еще несколько сущностей, к примеру `Сity`, `Region` и т.д. В каждой сущности повторяется конструкция `switch case`. Как сделать так, чтобы уникнуть дублирование кода? Думал, вынести данную функцию в сервис, но еще такого не встречал, что сервис инжектируется в к конструктор модели? Как правильно сделать?

Comment: вынесите switch в отдельную функцию constructorSwitch (можно и в сервис поместить) и вызывайте её с конструктора через `this.service.constructorSwitch.call(this)` На расширеный ответ нет времени, сори [ссылка](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, зачем выносить функцию в сервис, можно вынести функцию в отдельный файл. Во-вторых избегайте `magic numbers`, Ваш код теряет читабельность, для этого лучше используйте `const enum`, можете вынести его в отдельный файл для того, чтобы сделать `reusable`:

```
export const enum ParentLevels {
    Region = 1,
    Country = 2,
    Area = 3,
    City = 4,
    CityDistrict = 5,
    Place = 6,
    AdditionalTerritory = 90,
    AdditionalTerritorySubject = 91
}
```

Если у Вас данная конструкция `switch-case` повторяется, можете попробовать ключи вынести в `Map`:

```
export const getKeyMap = <T>(): Map<number, keyof T> => {
    return new Map<number, any>([
        [ParentLevels.Region, 'region'],
        [ParentLevels.Country, 'county'],
        [ParentLevels.Area, 'area'],
        [ParentLevels.City, 'city'],
        [ParentLevels.CityDistrict, 'city_district'],
        [ParentLevels.Place, 'place'],
        [ParentLevels.AdditionalTerritory, 'additional_territory'],
        [ParentLevels.AdditionalTerritorySubject, 'additional_territory_subject'],
   ]);
};
```

Далее в конструкторе:

```
const keyMap = getKeyMap<Street>();

for (let i = 0; i < this.parent_levels.length; i++) {
    const id = Number(this.parent_levels[i]);
    const key = keyMap.get(id);
    if (key !== undefined) {
        this[key] = this.parent_names[i];
    }
}
```

Но в случае если у Вас в каждой модели ключи будут разные, то максимум, что можно сделать это:

```
const id = Number(this.parents_levels[i]);
const parentName = this.parents_names[i];

switch (id) {
    case ParentLevels.Region:
        this.region = parentName;
        break;
    case ParentLevels.Country:
        this.county = parentName;
        break;
    case ParentLevels.Area:
        this.area = parentName;
        break;
    case ParentLevels.City:
        this.city = parentName;
        break;
    case ParentLevels.CityDistrict:
        this.city_district = parentName;
        break;
    case ParentLevels.Place:
        this.place = parentName;
        break;
    case ParentLevels.AdditionalTerritory:
        this.additional_territory = parentName;
        break;
    case ParentLevels.AdditionalTerritorySubject:
        this.additional_territory_subject = parentName;
        break;
}
```

И этого достаточно